# How to get the last changed table if they have the same table name and different table_PK

Tags: sql

I want to take the last changed record for multiple TableName and display it only one time.
For some TableName I have multiple Table_Pk, for exp:

```
SELECT COUNT(Table_PK), TableName
FROM TBL_TECTABLES INNER JOIN
     sys.tables
     ON 'TBL_Tec' + Table_PK = name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE LEN(name) = 39 
GROUP BY TableName 
HAVING COUNT(Table_PK) > 1
```

result looks like:

```
Table_PK   TableName
   9       L0L001T03
   2       L0L001T05
   ....
```

and I want to take Table_Pk, TableName once ordered by LastChanged.

Here is the code which I've tried but I get all records

```
SELECT  Distinct(Table_PK), TableName, LastChanged
FROM TBL_TECTABLES INNER JOIN
     sys.tables
     ON 'TBL_Tec' + Table_PK = name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE LEN(name) = 39 
ORDER BY LastChanged
```

result is:

```
Table_Pk                            TableName            LastChanged
91A5249DB797FF4BB44579AC7D3C0949    L0L003T41             2019-05-29
7070D39FAF65674DA8537B93FFDE2371    L0L003T41             2019-05-28 
......
```

I should have 1153 rows but I have 2220

Comment: Do you have an update date or timestamp column in your tables?

Comment: I have also validFrom, ValidTo, LastChanged(it is the update date) and created columns.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the most recent record per *table name*, then you can use window function partitioning on the table name:

```
SELECT Table_PK, TableName, LastChanged
FROM (SELECT tt.Table_PK, tt.TableName, tt.LastChanged,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tt.TableName ORDER BY tt.LastChanged DESC) as seqnum
      FROM TBL_TECTABLES tt INNER JOIN
           sys.tables t
           ON 'TBL_Tec' + tt.Table_PK = t.name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
      WHERE LEN(t.name) = 39 
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY LastChanged ;
```

I added table aliases, but had to guess where the columns come from.  You may need to adjust the table aliases.

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted a little bit and works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you need below query:

```
SELECT * from ( 
SELECT  Table_PK, TableName, LastChanged, row_numbeR() over(partition by table_pk order by lastchanged desc) as RN FROM TBL_TECTABLES 
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON 'TBL_Tec' + Table_PK = name 
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WHERE LEN(name) = 39 ) a Where RN = 1
```

Comment: Hi, no, it also retrieves me all records. I need to find records which have different Table_PK and the same TableName(like in the first code which I've put up) and from that i should get the rows which have tableName once(something like Distinct(TableName)), for Table_Pk that was modified the last.   I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: pls try modified query

Comment: `SELECT Distinct  TableName, Table_PK,LastChanged  FROM TBL_TECTABLES 
INNER JOIN sys.tables ON 'TBL_Tec' + Table_PK = name 
collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  WHERE LEN(name) = 39  
Order By LastChanged  desc`

Comment: I mean I modified my answer. Please retry.